# Static method Overloading Error

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, static, overloading

I have a problem with my overloading(or overriding) I am presuming. Every time I call with the driver class I created, it returns ("Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method duty(int) from the type Doctor"). How do I use the duty method when calling it through the doctor object.

Doctor Class

```
public class Doctor extends Employee {
    private int patientsSeen;

    public Doctor(int patientsSeen) {
        super(150000,45);
        this.patientsSeen = patientsSeen;

    }

    public void duty(int patientsSeen) {
        if(patientsSeen < 0) {
            System.out.println("Another Patient goes home happy!");
            this.patientsSeen = patientsSeen;
            System.out.println(patientsSeen + " patients sent home happy!");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Patients are waiting, get back to work!");  

    }
    public String toString() {
        super.toString();
        return patientsSeen + " ";
    }


}
```

Driver

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee doctor = new Doctor(0);
        Employee surgeon = new Surgeon(0);
        Janitor janitor = new Janitor(0);

        Janitor.duty(0);
        Doctor.duty(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: it should be `janitor.duty(0);` and `doctor.duty(0);`. These are instances method so you should call them via the objects you created, not the class as you are doing now.

Comment: @user2336315 you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Turing85 It should certainly be closed as a duplicate xxx which might already exists but too lazy to find :)

Comment: I'm flagging to close this as a "simple typographical error". In the question, it's stated that he's trying to call it through the doctor object, which signifies to me that he knows he needs to use the object but didn't notice that he used a capital D instead of a small D.

Comment: @Aify IMO it's not a simple typo but rather a huge misunderstanding of the difference between ClassName.method and instanceName.method, otherwise the OP wouldn't have asked this question and find his typo by himself.

Comment: @user2336315 **if he didn't mention the doctor object** in the question, I would've agreed with you completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Janitor** is the name of your class.
**janitor** is the name of your instance of your class **Janitor**.

When you are attempting to call a method specific to your instance, you need to refer to your instance janitor and not your class **Janitor**.

What you are looking for is:

```
janitor.duty(0);

doctor.duty(0);
```

Had you been using:

```
Janitor.duty(0);

Doctor.duty(0);
```

You would be calling this:

```
public static void duty(int patientsSeen) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a method on the class, not the instance.
It should be:

```
janitor.duty(0);
doctor.duty(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the nonstatic method 'duty(int)' as a static method. change it to:

```
janitor.duty(0);
doctor.duty(0);
```

and the code should work. You have to call them from an instance of 'Doctor' (or the superclass in which 'duty' is first implemented) or one of it's subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

One more important thing along with all the given answers. From you code it's seems it is neither overriding nor overloading. Now note some points:

1. If you `Employee` class has an **`non static`** and **non private** `duty(int )` method then at the child class `Doctor` it would be an overridden version of `duty(int )` method
2. If your `Employee` class has an static duty(int ) method then the `duty(int)` method can not be inherited to it's child class `Doctor` and hence it can not be overridden.
3. Now consider you `Employee` class has not a `duty(int )` method. But at your `Doctor` class you have two `duty()` method with these signature - `duty(int )` and `duty(float )`. Then it is said in `OOP` the `duty()` method has been overloaded for `int` and `float`

Comment: Thanks very much for the input this is my first post ever on here, and WOW the help has been amazing!